# Marshmallow runtime permission

Tags: android, permissions, camera

First of all THANKS IN ADVANCE TO YOU ALL , before coming and asking this question, i have searched alot to find answer for this, there are tons of questions like mine, but i was simply not abe to configure for what I need, so I hope that my question wil not receive duplicare , or i will get negative reputation. So i have made a flashlight app, and it still crashes on some devices that are using Android 6.0 and greater maybe 7, here is what i have done:

In onCreate i am requesting for permissions like this :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            startCamera();
        }
        else{
            String [] permissionRequest = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
            requestPermissions(permissionRequest, 
CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        startCamera();
    }
}
```

Outside the on create method I have overriden the onRequestPermission:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE){
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            startCamera();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"App cannot start wihout granted permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my startCamera() method:

```
private void startCamera() {
    flashLight = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);
    deviceHasFlash = getApplication().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    Button aboutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AboutBtn);
    aboutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PoupUp.class));
        }
    });

    if (!deviceHasFlash) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry, you device does not have a flash", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else {

        ////Here the app crashes on devices

        camera = Camera.open();
        parameter = camera.getParameters();
        camera.startPreview();
        hasCam = true;
    }//////

    flashLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
           isChecked = !isChecked;
           if (isChecked)
               flashLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
           else
                flashLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                turnOnOff(isChecked);
          }
    });


    SeekBar sbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    sbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            freq = progress;

        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
}
```

Also in AndroidManifest i have declared permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>;
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>;
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

Can you guys please help me to implement the permission reqest at runtime for Android 6.0 and greater, with toast messages, as right now, i have tried on emulator and this is the question for permission [Emulator photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eISp7.png), but my app does not takes photos and record anything as it is a flashlight app and i want to change that toast message , but on some phisical devices still crashe, i have to mention that i have tried to use PermissionDispatcher but i was not able to configure, so that is why I am calling for your help :).

Also the app crashes when I press the Overview Button(I think thah is how it is called, the one next to the home button),here is a picture of it ([Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6USR.jpg)) can you also help me with this? as i don't really know how it is called and i cannot finde a fix for it :)

Error log for permissio:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.bucur.mihai.flash/com.bucur.mihai.flash.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
 at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
   at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:525)
   at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:381)
   at com.bucur.mihai.flash.MainActivity.startCamera(MainActivity.java:110)
   at com.bucur.mihai.flash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6034)
   at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at
```

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

Error log for button press error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:616)
   at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6786)
   at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6955)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:735)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:679)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:62)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ListMenuPresenter.java:105)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$PanelFeatureState.getListMenuView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:2030)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.initializePanelContent(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1310)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.openPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1152)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onKeyUpPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1517)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onKeyUp(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:964)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:958)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:318)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2438)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4582)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4537)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4201)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4234)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4421)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2480)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2074)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2065)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2457)
   at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Can you share your error log?

Comment: @Scott i have edited, and added the error logs

Comment: Any ideas about how can I do it?

Comment: No one can't help me?